# UICollectionView odd-numbered cells are left blank

Tags: iphone, ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I'm making a `UICollectionView` with custom cells, and a very odd thing is happening. All the cells whose `indexPath.row`'s are **ODD** numbers are left blank, and I can't perform any drawing on them.

I have created a `UICollectionView` object in my own `UIViewController` using *Storyboard*. The `UICollectionView`'s cells are set to my custom `UICollectionViewCell` sublcass, named **CustomCell**. Each cell takes up the whole width and height of the `UICollectionView`. Everything inside the CustomCell is created programatically, not using Storyboard. Here is my `cellForItemAtIndexPath` code:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    //createViewWithDay is used to populate the contents of the cell
    [cell createViewWithDay:indexPath.row isToday:YES withSize:cell.frame.size];

    NSInteger x = indexPath.row;
    NSLog(@"Path: %i", x);

    return cell;
}
```

Each **CustomCell** creates a custom view (named **CustomView**), and adds it as a subview. Right now, all CustomView does is draw an X-Axis and a Y-Axis.

The weird thing is, `cellForItemAtIndexPath` is triggered correctly for each cell. That is, it is called for both even and odd indices. Same with the delegate method `didSelectItemAtIndexPath`. The drawing for each **CustomView** does NOT change based on the index of the cell. In fact, nothing changes at all based on the index. Here is an example of what appears when I run the app.

[image].

In the first picture, the cell with the axis drawn is at `indexPath.row == 14`, while the black cell is at `indexPath.row == 15`. In the second picture, index 15 is on the left with index 16 being on the right.[image]

Does anybody have any idea why this might be happening? The odd/even index might be irrelevant, but that is what's happening.

EDIT:
Some additional code..
Here is `createViewWithDay`, which is called in the `cellForItemAtIndex` method:

```
- (void)createViewWithDay:(float)day isToday:(BOOL)today withSize:(CGSize)size
{

    CustomView *newView = [[CustomView alloc] initWithFrame:self.frame];

    [newView viewForDay:day overDays:6 withDetail:20 today:YES withSize:size];

    [newView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [self addSubview:newView];
}
```

And here is `viewForDay`

```
- (void)viewForDay:(NSInteger)primaryDay overDays:(NSInteger)days withDetail:(NSInteger)detail today:(BOOL)today withSize:(CGSize)size
{
    _graphPrimaryDay = primaryDay;
    _numberOfDays = days;
    _lineDetail = detail;
    _isToday = today;
    _viewSize = self.frame.size;
    _pointsPerDay = (float)(_lineDetail / _numberOfDays);
    _isReadyToDraw = YES;

    [self createGraphDays];
}
```

This `viewForDay` method simply assigns some **CustomView** instance variables, while the `createGraphDays` method populates an NSMutableArray with dummy data.

I figure I should also add **CustomView**'s `drawRect` method, so here it is..

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    if(_isReadyToDraw)
    {
        [self drawGraph];
    }
}
```

And here is `drawGraph`..

```
- (void)drawGraph
{

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 0, _viewSize.height / 2);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, _viewSize.width, _viewSize.height / 2);

    if(_isToday)
    {
        CGContextMoveToPoint(context, _viewSize.width / 2, 0);
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, _viewSize.width / 2, _viewSize.height);
    }

    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 2.5);
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor blackColor].CGColor);

    CGContextStrokePath(context);
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post the code for `[cell createViewWithDay:indexPath.row isToday:YES withSize:cell.frame.size];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe I've found the solution to my problem. After the first two cells (indices 0 and 1), my custom view's `drawRect` method was no longer being called. For whatever reason, the custom view was being covered with the custom cell's background color, which was black. So I've fixed it by calling `setNeedsDisplay` on my custom view, so that it is forced to draw the correct image for every cell.

EDIT:

This is the answer that was correct for this instance of the problem, but I've actually run into the same problem for a different reason.

For the old solution, all I did was to make sure that `[cell createViewWithDay:isToday:withSize:]` (being called from `cellForRowAtIndexPath`) included a `[self.view setNeedsDisplay]`, so that the cell's view was being manually updated.

However, as I said, I've run into the same problem where every other cell was left blank, but for a different reason. In `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, I was calling a setup method for the cell. This method in turn would call a subview's setup method. One of the parameters for the subview's setup method was the cell's frame, so it would be something along the lines of (in `collectionViewCellSubclass`) `[self.view setupViewWithFrame:(CGRect)frame]`.

For the first cell, this worked fine, but for the second cell, the frame being passed to the view was `(320, 0, 320, 250)`. Because the cell had an origin of `(320, 0)` relative to the collection view, the cell's subview's origin would always be `(320, 0)`, but relative to the cell, so it would actually be placed off-screen. This was fixed by only initializing the subview's size, and making sure its origin was `(0, 0)`. This whole question has gotten awfully long now, but hopefully this alternate problem and solution will be helpful.

Comment: Please add some code here please. That may help someone.